# Unable to understand powershell code sourced from internet

Tags: powershell

I had a requirement to check if a software is installed on a machine. I tried WMIC query but it was not working for all the software.

I searched online to get the solution and found below PS code, which worked fine. With due respect to original author of code I tried to mold it to meet my requirements - which is could not as I don't understand the use of object array in this code.

When I check the value of `$Insdetails` I get:

[image: Output of '$insdetails']

Now I want to access the info `displayverison` by using `$insdetails.displayversion` and that is not returning anything.

I know I am missing on basic principles but wish to understand how to handle this situation. I am fresher in Powershell and need guidance from experts in this matter, please educate me to understand the nuances.

```
$computername = $env:computername
$uninstallKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"  
$reg = [microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername)
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 
$subkeys = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames()  
$array = @()

foreach ($key in $subkeys) {
    $thisKey = $UninstallKey + "\\" + $key 
    $thisSubKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computername
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"))
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))
    $array += $obj
} 

$InsDetails = ($array | Where-Object { $_.Displayname -like '*vlc*' } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | ft -auto)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having is because on the end of your last command you have `| ft -auto`. `FT` is an alias of `Format-Table`. When you send output to one of the `Format-` cmdlets it changes the object type and you can't really work any further with the object or its properties other than to redirect it to a file or printer, or the screen.

To do what you require, simply remove the `| ft -auto` part.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the explanation. it has fixed the problem i was having.